SwiftUI @AppStorage causes views to refresh/reinitialize with DragGesture
I have a weird issue on SwiftUI iOS 18, when using DragGesture and dragging a view from the left side of the screen (In that cases), causes any View and Sub-View with @AppStorage in it to reinitialize which causes for a junky animation
    ZStack {

        DestinationTabs()
             .presentVideoPlayer()
        
        SideMenuView(show: $show)
            .offset(x: -Constants.sideMenuWidth)
            .offset(x:max( min(dragging.width + position.width ,Constants.sideMenuWidth),0) )

    }
    .simultaneousGesture(
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged { value in
                
                withAnimation(.linear) {
                    if position.width == 0 && value.translation.width < 0 {
                        self.dragging = .zero
                    } else {
                        if value.startLocation.x <= 30 && self.position.width < Constants.sideMenuWidth{
                            self.dragging = value.translation
                            let adjustment = position.width == Constants.sideMenuWidth ? 0 : (value.translation.width / 625)
                            self.scale = position.width + value.translation.width >= Constants.sideMenuWidth ? 0.9 : max(1 - abs(adjustment), 0.9)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .onEnded { value in
                    withAnimation(.linear)  {
                        if value.translation.width >= 50 && value.startLocation.x <= 30{
                            self.position.width += (value.translation.width > 0) ? Constants.sideMenuWidth : -Constants.sideMenuWidth
                        } else if self.position.width != Constants.sideMenuWidth{
                            self.position.width = 0
                            self.scale = 1.0
                        }
                        self.dragging = .zero
                    }
            })

With the above code, any view within "DestinationTabs" refresh itself multiple time when onChanged is called.
After few days of debugging, I observed that deleting @AppStorage vars/properties from the view completely resolves the issue, DragGesture does not modify any @AppStorage vars and it's simply moving the SideMenuView from left to right.
Any ideas?
Edit:
Just for the sake of testing, I removed the value of the @AppStorage from any view/method and even created a dummy @AppStorage var, the behaviour persisted among them...

Are you changing any @State or @Binding values from within .onChanged? I'm presuming you are, given the view is not mutable. If you're updating state, be sure that your usage of that view isn't conflicting with one another.

I already checked, they are not conflicting with any other, "dragging" "scale" and "position" are all @State, but they are using only on SideMenuView
